# How to change CSS when scroll to an element?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 section, include: `section-1`, `section-2` and `section-3`.

When I scroll to `section-2`, it will change the background color menu (a children element of `section-2`).

Normally, I usually code:

```
var section = $("#section-2")
var sectionOffSet = section2.offset().top;
var sectionHeight = section2.height();

var $w_scroll = $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($w.scrollTop() >= sectionOffSet && $w.scrollTop() <= (sectionOffSet + sectionHeight)) {
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#fff'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'#26ace2'});
  }else{
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#26ace2'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)'});
  }
});
```

To apply HTML, but in my case, I have element hidden, need click button `Load More` to show more element.

HTML code:

```
<section class="section-1">
    <div class="group-img-case-study col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="group-case-study">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" ><img class='img-case-study' src="<?php echo upload_url().'case-study/case-study-1.png' ?>" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="group-case-study">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" ><img class='img-case-study' src="<?php echo upload_url().'case-study/case-study-2.png' ?>" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="group-img-case-study col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="group-case-study">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" ><img class='img-case-study' src="<?php echo upload_url().'case-study/case-study-1.png' ?>" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="group-case-study">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" ><img class='img-case-study' src="<?php echo upload_url().'case-study/case-study-2.png' ?>" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 group-load-more-case-study text-center btn_load_more">
        <span id="loadMore"><img class="img-load-more-case-study" src="<?php echo upload_url().'case-study/load-more.png' ?>" alt="Load more"></span>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="section-2">

</section>

<section class="section-3">

</section>
```

And JS file in function `Load More`:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('div.group-case-study').slice(0, 2).show();
    if ($("div.group-case-study:hidden").length == 0) {
        $('.btn_load_more').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
    $('#loadMore').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("div.group-case-study:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();

      if ($("div.group-case-study:hidden").length == 0) {
        $('.btn_load_more').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I think the height of `section-1` effect when I scroll to `section-2`. It's can't change the background of a menu.

But I don't know calculator to do that.

I think this image will show more information.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a working code snippet with images.

Comment: see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with your code? First, try to see if the jQuery detects the sections okay printing in the console log. And set "!important" to the CSS rules if it doesn't work.
It might look like this:

```
if ($w.scrollTop() >= sectionOffSet && $w.scrollTop() <= (sectionOffSet + sectionHeight)) {
    console.log('Section detected');
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#fff'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'#26ace2 !important'});
}else{
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#26ace2'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) !important'});
}
```

Comment: I checked. `!important` not working. Can you see more information at updated my question? Thanks for @Miguel M. Serrano.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery css function

> !important

not working
you cant do this like that

> $('.menu-bg').attr("style","background: #26ace2 !important;");